# Extracting subfolders into a specific folder

Tags: command-line, 7zip, rar

I have a bunch of sub-folders with respective `rar` and `7z` files. How do I extract all of these and tell the pipe to output to a specific folder?

Comment: All archives at once?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to extract all `.rar` and `.7z` files recursively, it will save the output to `/directory/to/save` :

```
find . -type f \( -name '*.rar' -o -name '*.7z' \) \
  -exec 7z e -o/directory/to/save {} \;
```

Run this from the parent directory containing the subdirectories that have the `7z` and `rar` files. Also replace `/directory/to/save` with the actual path to the directory you want to save the uncompressed files.

`7z` comes with the `p7zip` package, you need to install it (if not done already), to get the `rar` file support you need `p7zip-rar` too :

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full p7zip-rar
```

`7z` has a recursive option (`-r`) but seems misleading as `man 7z` says:

```
-r[-|0]
            Recurse subdirectories (CAUTION: this flag does not do what 
you think, avoid using it)
```